# Tool to find cause of dead lock in Java application

Tags: java, locking, profiling, monitoring, deadlock

We can reproduce a situation where part of your system freezes. We suspect that this might be due to a locking problem.

How can we find out where every thread of our application is currently at? Which tool can we use to find the spot where the deadlock occurs?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942658/static-analysis-tool-to-detect-multithreading-problems-deadlocks-race-conditio

Comment: you can use the browser debugging tools if it's a web application else try adding comments in every place where you think the deadlock might occure and trace through them to find the source of your problem

Comment: @BhandariS heard about JConsole, JVisualVM? These tools provide deadlock detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a Thread dump of your running process to see stack traces of all the thread running at that time.

Its a good idea to take multiple Thread dumps in an interval of 5-10 secs so that you can compare the activity of threads in different dumps.

There are multiple ways to take Thread dump of an application:

1. If you have jstack on the machine where process is running,

   ```
   jstack {pid} > threaddump.log
   ```
2. kill -3 {pid}
3. Using jvisiualvm or jconsole, you can connect to the local/remote process and generate the threaddump

Answer (score 3):

You could use the jstack utility, it shows stack traces for java processes. You'll find it in the bin directory of your JDK. See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstack.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you want something with a graphical display, you can use [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), whose locking graph shows a deadlock in red:

[image]

It also allows you to analyze locking situations over time.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler

Answer (score 2):

Adquire a threaddump (jconsole, kill -3 pid, etc) and analyze it with [Samurai](http://samuraism.jp/samurai/en/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the thread that is causing the deadlock, you can use ThreadMXBean .
Here is a very good example of how to do it:

[deadlock detection using ThreadMXBean](http://javaconceptoftheday.com/detect-deadlocked-threads-using-threadmxbean-class-java/)

Also here is a link from oracle haw to use jstack. Jstack it may be more usefull to you as it will show you which threads are waiting for a resource, for which resource and it will also tell you which thread holds the resource:

[oracle docs link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/hangloop.html)